# Touchpad and Keyboard not working 18.04

Tags: apt, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

First and foremost I apologize if this is a simple solution that's going over my head as I have zero prior experience with Linux or Ubuntu or anything and I'm still learning the ropes. I've been trying to figure this out on my own for about 2 hours now and I'm starting to go in circles so I need some help.

Everything so far has been on a live version of the OS, I haven't uninstalled windows just yet even though that's my eventual plan. I'm not sure if this being the live version would affect anything regarding the installation of drivers and such.

At least some of the keyboard initially worked at some point on the boot menu as I was able to adjust the volume and the other hotkeys worked when I was messing with them trying to get the touchpad to work, however the touchpad wouldn't work at all and I have an external KB/M connected for now. However upon actually entering the live version of the OS the keyboard no longer works as well. This at least give me hope as Ubuntu obviously detected the keyboard at some point.

With `xinput list` the touchpad isn't showing up there. I read somewhere that I may just be out of luck if it's not showing up here but I'm hoping there's more to it as this touchpad has been wacky in the past with drivers when doing a fresh Windows install. All that shows is just the Virtual Core XTEST pointer and the external one so I figured I would start here. I read something about the synaptics driver and how most touchpads use that so I looked into getting it installed.

I tried `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and I was unable to locate the package so I looked into that and ended up using

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates`

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To be honest I'm not too sure what I'm doing here or if it actually did anything but the outputs made it seem like something was happening so I went with it. In the post I read where I got these lines of codes from, it mentioned something about the package name being different or something like that so I tried both of these

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Both of which returned me with "unable to locate package". I plan on looking into some other solutions but this where I've been stuck and I'm tired of trying to brute force it and going in circles. Any help is appreciated and once again I do apologize if it's something a google search should have fixed (even though I've done at least a hundred by now) but my brain is jello.

Answer (score 0):

Removing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

and installing xserver-xorg-input-all worked for me

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt upgrade
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with Ubuntu 20.04. I had to combine the above solutions together:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt upgrade
reboot
```